# pyttsx3 | Issues Initializing on MacOs

Tags: python, macos, text-to-speech, pyobjc, pyttsx3

I have a question regarding Python's "Text to Speech" module pyttsx3.

My Goal:

- Run pyttsx3 to speak a string of text.

Where I Stand:

- Installed pyttsx3
- Wrote the following lines in VS Code:

```
import pyttsx3
  engine = pyttsx3.init("nsss")
  engine.say("Hello World")
  engine.runAndWait()
```

Where I am Stuck:

- The code will not properly initialize.

See Error Message Below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-                         packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
        eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/weakref.py", line     136, in __getitem__
        o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
    KeyError: 'nsss'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/drewpeterson/Documents/Programming/Python/CS50/speech.py", line 6, in <module>
        engine = pyttsx3.init("nsss")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-    packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
        eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-        packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
        self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
        self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File         "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-    packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 2, in <module>
        from Foundation import *
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1403, in _handle_fromlist
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 160, in __getattr__
        value = self.__calc_all()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 328, in __calc_all
        all_names.update(p.__all__)
                     ^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 160, in __getattr__
        value = self.__calc_all()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/objc/_lazyimport.py", line 257, in __calc_all
        objc.loadBundleVariables(self.__bundle, dct, varmap)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/objc/_pythonify.py", line 52, in numberWrapper
        if isinstance(obj, NSDecimalNumber):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    objc.internal_error: PyObjC: internal error in _type_lookup at Modules/objc/objc-        object.m:380: assertion failed: dict && PyDict_Check(dict)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you put only irrelevant tags for your question, but leave out the relevant _python_ tag. Aside from this, you didn't say how you executed your program.

Comment: Good catch on the tags -- they were from a previous query. For context, I am trying to learn the pyttsx3 module. When I executed the aforementioned lines in VS Code, I received the error message. Thanks for any support!

Comment: How did you install pyttsx3 and Python? I (PyObjC maintainer) cannot reproduce the issue when using the python.org installer to install Python 3.12 and "pip install pyttsx3" to install pyttsx3.  I did have to patch the nsss driver a bit though due to other problems (in particular: add "import objc; from objc.super" to the top of the module to address missing imports.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize `pyttsx3` with `nsss` on Mac. I've had the same problem.

Run `pip install py3-tts`. You won't need a driver for `pyttsx3.init()` anymore.